# Can Blender work on Surface pro (Gen5)?

Tags: animation

I have Surface Pro(5th gen)Model 1796 i7 and it has Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7660U CPU @ 2.50GHz 2.50 GHz. Will this run Blender so I can animate?

Answer (score 1):

Blender can 'work' on the given-specifications-machine.

Note that blender can work on really low-powered machines, the specifications are given on the [Requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) page on Blender's official website.
If you are asking that if your specifications are *'good-enough'* for rendering animations, then it all depends on what type of animations do you want to create and their complexity. But if you are just into learning Blender, these are perfectly fine.

PS:- You have not mentioned your RAM limit, but if it is 8GB - 16GB or more, you are good to go.